# Problem with addEventListener and sorting items in angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, addeventlistener, angular8

I tried to implement sorting function in my table by clicking on header of the column. It should work like this: On first click items in that column should be in asceding order, on second click items should be in descending order.

Here is my code in html:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th (click)="sorting('FirstName')" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Ime i prezime : activate to sort column ascending">
      First Name
    </th>                
    <th (click)="sorting('Email')" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Email : activate to sort column ascending">
      Email
    </th>
    <th (click)="sorting('Username')" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Username: activate to sort column ascending">
      Username
    </th>                 
    <th>
      Actions
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Here is my code in typescript file:

```
sorting(sortBy) {
  this.sortBy = sortBy;
  let tableHeaderItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sorting'));

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.currentTarget.classList);
    if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('sorting_asc')) {
      e.currentTarget.classList.remove('sorting_asc');
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('sorting_desc');
      this.sortDirection = "desc";
    }
    else if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('sorting_desc')) {
      e.currentTarget.classList.remove('sorting_desc');
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('sorting_asc');
      this.sortDirection = "asc";
    }
    else {
      tableHeaderItems.forEach(node => {
        node.classList.remove('sorting_asc');
        node.classList.remove('sorting_desc');
      });
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('sorting_asc');
      this.sortDirection = "asc";
    }
  }

  tableHeaderItems.forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
  });

  this.service.getAll(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
}
```

I have problem - on each click the function is just one time, but `const handleClick` is called multiple times. When I clicked on my column for the first time, nothing happens inside const handleClick. When I clicked for the second time, it called only ones. But when I clicked for the third time on my column, it called two times. If I clicked on my column for the tenth time, it will call handleClick nine times. Very strange behaviour. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You are adding event listener on each click and that's why you are having that behaviour. What you should do is add event listener only once.

Comment: I would: 1) remove all `addEventListener`, all `querySelector`, all `classList` occurences from the code, 2) use Angular's event bindings and Angular class bindings.

Comment: @mbojko is right, do not manipulate the DOM yourself.

Comment: @mbojko, could you please add an answer?

Comment: Hsuan Lee's answer is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use DOM.

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th (click)="sorting('FirstName')"
      class="sorting"
      [ngClass]="sortBy === 'FirstName' ? { 'sorting_asc': sortDirection === 'asc', 'sorting_desc':  sortDirection === 'desc' } : null">
      First Name
    </th>
    <th (click)="sorting('Email')"
      class="sorting"
      [ngClass]="sortBy === 'Email' ? { 'sorting_asc': sortDirection === 'asc', 'sorting_desc':  sortDirection === 'desc' } : null">
      Email
    </th>
    <th (click)="sorting('Username')"
      class="sorting"
      [ngClass]="sortBy === 'sorting' ? { 'sorting_asc': sortDirection === 'asc', 'sorting_desc':  sortDirection === 'desc' } : null">
      Username
    </th>
    <th>
      Actions
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

```
  sorting(sortBy) {
    this.sortBy = sortBy;
    this.sortDirection = this.sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    this.service.getAll(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
  }
```

Comment: the problem is now when I click on "FirstName" column all other columns get "sorting_asc" class.

Comment: Well done, I am so thankful to you and all other guys.